# How to dump sip traces according to ip in separate files?

Tags: voip, tcpdump, tshark, opensips

I have Opensips running on a static ip "192.168.1.60" to which multiple users are registered with different Ips. Like

```
User A ip ="192.168.1.43"
User B ip ="192.168.1.33"
User C ip ="192.168.1.23" etc
```

I want Sip dump traces, user wise(their ip based) into separate files. How can i do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

tcpdump -nq -s 0 -A -vvv port 5060 and host 1.2.3.4 -w

Use the Host condition to isolate traffic from different hosts. If the Host addresses are already known.

Else you capture one and run filters on Wireshark or any other packet capture software as needed to extract.